# react-router 4 - Browser history needs a DOM

Tags: react-router-v4

I am trying server side rendering using react-router 4. I am following the example provided here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering/putting-it-all-together

As per the example on server we should use `StaticRouter`. When I import as per the example I am seeing StaticRouter as undefined

```
import {StaticRouter} from 'react-router';
```

After doing some research online I found I could use `react-router-dom`. Now my import statement looks like this.

```
import {StaticRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
```

However when I run the code I am getting `Invariant Violation: Browser history needs a DOM` in the browser.

my server.js file code

```
....
app.get( '*', ( req, res ) => {
  const html = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../index.html')).toString();
  const context = {};
  const markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context} >
      <App/>
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  if (context.url) {
    res.writeHead(302, {
      Location: context.url
    })
    res.end();
  } else {
      res.send(html.replace('$react', markup));
  }
} );
....
```

And my client/index.js code

```
....
ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
), root);
....
```

---

**Update v1**
Reduced my example to a bear minimum and still getting the same error.

**clientIndex.js**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from '../App'

ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App/>
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

**serverIndex.js**

```
import { createServer } from 'http'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router'
import App from '../App'

createServer((req, res) => {
  const context = {}

  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter
      location={req.url}
      context={context}
    >
      <App/>
    </StaticRouter>
  )

res.write(`
  <!doctype html>
  <div id="app">${html}</div>
`)
res.end()
}).listen(3000);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import routes from "./client/routes";
const App = ( ) => (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" exact render={( props ) => ( <div>Helloworld</div> )} />
  </Router>
)

export default App;
```

Comment: I managed to solve it.

I don't need to wrap my <Route> inside <BrowserRouter> in App.js. Because I am was already wrapping it <BrowserRouter> in clientIndex.js

Comment: I'm dealing with routing for the first time now...  I think you might be able to install the [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) package and use `createMemoryHistory()` and pass that to the 'history' property (i.e. `<Router history={ history }>`

Comment: @Saf thanks a lot.. your solution worked like a charm and i was looking for and idol setup of isomorphic structure but didn't found anything working.. your code rocked..!!

Answer (score 28):

You need to use different history provider for server side rendering because you don't have a real DOM (and browser's history) on server. So replacing BrowserRouter with Router and an alternate history provider in your app.js can resolve the issue. Also you don't have to use two wrappers. You are using BrowserRouter twice, in app.js as well as clientIndex.js which is unnecessary.

```
import { Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';

const history = createMemoryHistory();

  <Router history={history}>
   <Route path="/" exact render={( props ) => ( <div>Helloworld</div> )} />
  </Router>
```

You can now replace StaticRouter with ConnectedRouter which can be used both in client and server. I use the following code to choose between history and export it to be used in ConnectedRouter's history.

```
export default (url = '/') => {
// Create a history depending on the environment
  const history = isServer
    ? createMemoryHistory({
        initialEntries: [url]
     })
   : createBrowserHistory();
}
```

Comment: I assume that `isServer` is a simple `if statement` that checks if its the server or not?

Answer (score 13):

In clientIndex.js

Rather than BrowserRouter use StaticRouter.

> import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
>
> import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

Comment: changing it to StaticRouter resulted in a crash of node and my webpack watch...I don't think this is a good solution.

Answer (score 5):

As is essentially noted in the comments, one may hit this error (as I have) by accidentally wrapping your App component in a `<BrowserRouter>`, when instead it is your *client* app that should be wrapped.

#### App.js

```
import React from 'react'

const App = () => <h1>Hello, World.</h1>

export default App
```

#### ClientApp.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'

const render = Component => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Component />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  )
}

render(App)
```

See also the [React Router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering/putting-it-all-together).

Comment: that doesn't answer the question and it's fairly vague, what's Component ?

Comment: `Component` is the React component taken by the `render` function.

Comment: The question notes an error `Invariant Violation: Browser history needs a DOM`, that can occur from wrapping the `<BrowserRouter>` around the incorrect component. [This is also noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058684/react-router-4-browser-history-needs-a-dom/45043410?noredirect=1#comment73205862_43058684).