# What does it meant - Browser history needs a DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, server-side-rendering, browser-history

I'm a beginner in React and stuck with some problem. I got an error Browser history needs a DOM, I'm using Server side rendering. I have visited many websites but still not got any exact answer that what does it does it mean and why it occurs ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-router 4 - Browser history needs a DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058684/react-router-4-browser-history-needs-a-dom)

Comment: @JózefPodlecki I have read that but can't able to understand why Server don't have real DOM and why we use history provider ?

Comment: `DOM` comes with the rendered web page. That's why you can access `document` object and use all of its api when running on client. On the server side however you don't have that. The same goes with History api